# Using single-quotes in Jenkins Declarative Pipeline for credentials doesn't pass the full secret text

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Following the instructions here:
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#string-interpolation

I wrote this code on the Jenkinsfile:

```
    (...) stage("publish"){
            steps{
                withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'ECR_authenticate', variable: 'get_authenticate')]) {
                echo "pushing the image to AWS ECR"
                sh ('$get_authenticate') \
                 ... (rest of code)
                }
```

Getting me back an error :
 `Unknown options: |,docker,login,--username,AWS,--password-stdin,77777790668.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

When using double quotes: `"${get_authenticate}"`  the code works, however this will be insecure and against the documentation.

Anyone know how to solve this puzzle?

Comment: Is `$get_authenticate` an environment variable?

Comment: It is the variable assigned for the secret.

Comment: Using double codes evalutes the variable to it's value, using single quotes just prints the text/name out. You could test that in a simpe script with `echo '${USER}'`vs. `echo "${USER}"`. I don't see how you can evalute variables without the "insecurity" of maybe not getting what you desire.

Comment: If you are fully confident that this is being done correctly, and the variable is not being propagated as an environment variable for shell interpreter interpolation, then you may want to file an issue.